# Collectionview with Different items in a row

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

Okay. My Collectionview works fine. But I want to change my layout a bit.
I have an array with different numbers so is array.count = 5 , I need 5 items in a row. 
I don't know how to display this in my Collectionview .

Thanks for help.

UPDATE:

now every Row is for example 6 !

but i don't know how to handle with an array of numbers!

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let numberOfCellInRow : Int = 6
        let padding : Int = 1
        let collectionCellWidth : CGFloat = (self.view.frame.size.width/CGFloat(numberOfCellInRow)) - CGFloat(padding)
        return CGSize(width: collectionCellWidth, height: 200)



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing sizeForItemAtIndexPath, which is part of the protocol of UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, is how to set the dimensions of a UICollectionViewCell dynamically (i.e., at runtime).

In sizeForItemAtIndexPath, create a CGSize object which is how big you'd like each UICollectionViewCell to be, and simply use that object as the return value of the function.  In your example, the width of that CGSize object would approximately be the width of the main view divided by 5.  I say approximately because you will also need room for padding between the cells as well as perhaps some non-zero sectionInsets around each section of the UICollectionView.

To set the padding between the cells, go to the attributes inspector pane in the storyboard for your UICollectionView object, and put the attributes pane in "Measurements mode".  You'll see "Min Spacing", both "For Cells" and "For Lines". The "For Cells" field is where you can specify the horizontal spacing you'd like between the cells.  The "For Lines" field is where you can specify the vertical spacing you'd like between the cells.